# Car wheel metal vibration noise when I hit it (car is stationary) (SOLVED)

Tags: wheels, suspension

I have a toyota wigo 2019 and its front right wheel is making this high pitch metalic vibration noise when I hit/kick the top of the tire, and the vibration noise is a bit louder and linger a bit longer than the other wheels. What caused it is probably the pothole I drove over.

No vibration when driving.
No noise when turning while driving/stationary.
No play on the wheel and the other suspension parts when I elevated the wheel in question and checked.

I have little car knowledge and will have the wheel looked at by a professional but I would like to have a rough idea of whats probably happening with the wheel so I dont get scammed.

Ill try to get back here after its fixed and post what the problem is and whats replaced (if there are any)

thanks.

Comment: If you hit a pothole you could take the vehicle in for an alignment check anyway, without mentioning your concerns and see what they tell you at first.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. It was the spring in the struts, when I hit the tire while holding the spring in place it doesnt produce the sound.

Comment: Instead of editing your OP title to say "solved", take the [tour] to see the proper way of telling people that this has a resolution. (HINT: see that check mark over there to the left? Yeah, a simple click...)